# Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in table

Tags: latex

I have the next table, but it shows the warning of the title.

```
            \begin{table}[!hbt]
            \centering
            \caption{Learning Types}
            \begin{tabular}{| p{0.14\textwidth} | p{0.42\textwidth} | p{0.34\textwidth} |}
                
                \hline Supervised Learning & The data you feed to the algorithm is labeled.        
                                             It is often used for classification and regression  &  \Centerstack{\\k-Nearest Neighbors\\Linear Regression\\
                                                                                                           Logistic Regression\\Support Vector Machines (SVMs)\\
                                                                                                           Decision Trees and Random Forests\\Neural networks\\} \tabularnewline
                \hline Unsupervised Learning & hh & hh \tabularnewline
                \hline Semi-supervised Learning & hh & hh \tabularnewline
                \hline Reinforcement Learning & hh & hh \tabularnewline \hline
            \end{tabular}
            \end{table}
```

I have searched, and some people say that is because the \\ (now \tabularnewline),
but i do not know how to make dissapear the warning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `p{<len>}` column specification tries to justify any multiline content, stretching it out so it is both flush left and flush right with the column boundary (except for the last line). In your case, there's no way to stretch out `Supervised` to fit exactly within `0.14\textwidth`, causing the "Underfull `\hbox`" warning.

Since that column is so narrow, it's better to force some alignment/spacing using `\makecell` (from the [`makecell` package](//ctan.org/pkg/makecell)). Below I've also used [`booktabs`](//ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) and [`tabularx`](//ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) to improve the visual appeal.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs,makecell,tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Learning Types}
  \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ l X l }
    \toprule
    \thead{Type} & \thead{Description} & \thead{Example(s)} \\
    \midrule
    \makecell[lt]{Supervised \\ Learning} & 
      The data you feed to the algorithm is labeled.
      It is often used for classification and regression &
      \makecell[lt]{%
        $k$-Nearest Neighbors             \\
        Linear Regression                 \\
        Logistic Regression               \\
        Support Vector Machines (SVMs)    \\
        Decision Trees and Random Forests \\
        Neural networks%
      } \\
    \addlinespace[10pt]
    \makecell[lt]{Unsupervised \\ Learning} & Description & Example(s) \\
    \addlinespace[10pt]
    \makecell[lt]{Semi-supervised \\ Learning} & Description & Example(s) \\
    \addlinespace[10pt]
    \makecell[lt]{Reinforcement \\ Learning} & Description & Example(s) \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks terrific and great explanation! Thank you :D